# Create and link to a browser cached temporary file using javascript or shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, browser, browser-cache

I am developing in R/Shiny (which mainly makes use of JavaScript) to display the results of the web applications.

In one of our application, we must create an XML file and redirect the user to an URL that has this XML file path in its URL as an argument.

Something like :

```
http://path.to.my.service:1234/file=u:\my\shared\myxml.xml
```

At the moment, we create the file "myxml.xml" in a folder that is mounted both in the user and the server file system but I found this really unpractical and ugly. I'd rather create a file in the user local file system and have the link point to it.

I'd like something like :

```
http://path.to.my.service:1234/file=C:\Users\moi\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\monprofil\myxml.xml
```

To this of course, I need :

- to be able to create an XML file in an accessible dedicated directory (e.g. the browser cache dir)
- to be able to have to path to it.

Do you see any way to achieve this kind of results?
Many thanks for your kind help.

Sylvain

Comment: What is the xml file used for? Should the user be able to edit it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The XML file would be used as a "session file" for the program IGV (genomic sequence visualisation tool). The user is not supposed to edit it. IGV listens to a given port (hence localhost:1234) and use the session file when a link is opened.

Comment: library([shinyStore](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore)) might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks ... I'll have a look asap

Comment: How do you want to create the file in the user's file system? Normally web pages can't do that because that would be a big security issue if the site could overwrite any file on your computer.

Comment: @ismirsehregal : just had a look at shinystore. seems nice to store values but not complete files unfortunately

Comment: @MrFlick : I know. But, you have files in the browser cache (e.g. for storing pictures / vids), so why not an XML?

Comment: @SylvainBrohee you can read the xml into an R obj., store it via shinyStore, read it on session start and save it into a temp file again (if a file is required).

Comment: @ismirsehregal I want to store the file in a locally accessible location under the form of an XML. I click a button, it generates a local XML (say c:\path\to\file.xml) somewhere and I use javascript to directly open a local webservice that uses the path  to the file as parameter (e.g. javascript windows.open (localhost:1234/c:\path\to\file.xml)).